# how to use ReactiveMongo in play framework filter?

Tags: mongodb, filter, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I am going to use ReactiveMongo in Play filter, How can i do this?

I can only find sample for using ReactiveMongo in Controller.
How can i access to db.collection in a Play filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stéphane Godbillon for his answer in ReactiveMongo google group:

> You can call the `connection` on the object `ReactiveMongoPlugin` (in the package play.modules.reactivemongo) in your filter.

```
  val connection =  ReactiveMongoPlugin.connection(play.api.Play.current)
  val db = connection("your-db")

  def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("your-collection")
```